# Multithreaded Disaster Client Server

Tags: java, client-server

I send information to the server, the server hangs for all eternity, any guidance is much appreciated. I think the problem is with one of the conidtional statements or the dataoutputstream but idk.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;




public class Client {

public Client(Socket newSocket, int ID) {
    // Set properties
    id = ID;
    socket = newSocket;
    connected = true;
    // Get input
    inport = new Inport();
    inport.start();
}

public static int conversion(int serverValue) {
    if (serverValue >= 10) {
        return 10;
    } else
        return serverValue;
}

/**
 * Handles all incoming data from this user.
 */
private class Inport extends Thread {
    private ObjectInputStream in;
    //private DataInputStream in;

    public void run() {
        // Open the InputStream
        try {
            in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not get input stream from " + toString());
            return;
        }
        // Announce
        System.out.println(socket + " has connected input.");

        // Enter process loop
        while (true) {
            // Sleep
            try {
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(toString() + " has input interrupted.");
            }
        }
    }
}

static String standOrHit = "";
private Socket socket;
private boolean connected;
private Inport inport;
static int serverValue;
static String serverName = "127.0.0.1"; //Our Server Name
static String selection = "";
static int port = 9999; //Our Server
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
static boolean isTurn = true;
static boolean isGameOver = false;
static int score = 0;
static String sh = "It's your turn. Enter 'H' for Hit or 'S' for stand) \n Score:" + score;
static int id = 500;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    System.out.println("Fetching server connection...");
    Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port); //Create a Client Socket and attempt to connect to the server @ port
    System.out.println("Connection Established.");
    System.out.println("Fetching Player ID...");
    System.out.println("Game Found you're Player " + 3 + ".");
    System.out.println("Waiting for server...");

    OutputStream outputStream = client.getOutputStream(); //Create a stream for sending data
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outputStream); //Wrap that stream around a DataOutputStream

    //InputStream is used for reading
    InputStream inputStream = client.getInputStream(); //Read the incoming stream as bytes
    DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream); //Read the inputStream and convert to primative times

  //  while (isGameOver == false) {
        //Ask the User if what they want to do
        System.out.println(sh);
        selection = keyboard.nextLine();
        //If they choose H
       //if (selection.equals("H")) {
            //Send the H to the Server(Works)
            out.writeUTF(selection);
            out.flush();
            //Add server score to our score
            // System.out.println(dataInputStream.readUTF());
            while (dataInputStream.available() > 0) {
                serverValue = dataInputStream.readInt();
            }
            score += conversion(serverValue);
            System.out.println("Drew a " + serverValue + ".");
            System.out.println("Waiting for player " + id);
            //Loop back until
      //  }
        //If they choose to stand just send S
        if (selection.equals("S"))
        {
            //Send the H to the Server(Works)
            out.writeUTF(selection);
            out.flush();
        }

   // }
}
```

}

Server

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * 
 */
public class Server extends Thread implements Runnable{

private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private Socket socket;
private ArrayList<Client> clients = new ArrayList<Client>();
private boolean isGameOver = false;
private Random rand;
private int scoreToAdd;

public Server(int port) throws  IOException
{
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port,2);
    rand = new Random();

}


//Thread to execute once t.Start is called
public void run()
{


    //Just as we are awaiting,print to the user.
    System.out.println("Server started. Finding Clients...");
    //System.out.println("Waiting for client on port : " + serverSocket.getLocalPort() + " ... ");
    Socket server = null;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream ;
    //InputStream is used for reading
    InputStream inputStream; //Read the incoming stream as bytes
    DataInputStream dataInputStream; //Read the inputStream and convert to primative times



    try {
        //If the server is accepted, connect the user
        //System.out.println("Connection Established.");

        // Get a client trying to connect
        server = serverSocket.accept();
        //dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
        //inputStream = server.getInputStream();
        //dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);

        // Client has connected
        System.out.println("Found Client "+ (clients.size()+1));
        // Add user to list
        clients.add(new Client(server,1));
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (true)
    {
        try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            inputStream = server.getInputStream();
            dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
            // Client has connected
            System.out.println("Found Client "+ (clients.size()+1));
            System.out.println("Initiating Game...");
            // Add user to list
            clients.add(new Client(socket,1));
            clients.get(0).isTurn = true;

            while(isGameOver == false || ((clients.get(0).standOrHit.equals("S") && clients.get(1).standOrHit.equals("S")) == false))
            {
                if(clients.get(0).isTurn) {
                    System.out.println("Player 1's Turn");
                        if (dataInputStream.readUTF().equals("H")) {
                            //Generate a random number (Works)
                            System.out.println("Got H from Client");

                            //Send the random number in a outputbuffer (Works)
                            dataOutputStream.write(rand.nextInt(13) + 1);
                            dataOutputStream.flush();
                            clients.get(0).isTurn = false;
                            clients.get(1).isTurn = true;
                            }

                }
                else if (clients.get(1).isTurn)
                {
                    System.out.println("Player 2's Turn");
                    if(dataInputStream.readUTF().equals("H"))
                    {
                        //Generate a random number (Works)
                        //System.out.println(rand.nextInt(13)+1);

                        //Send the random number in a outputbuffer (Works)
                        dataOutputStream.write(rand.nextInt(13)+1);
                        dataOutputStream.flush();
                        clients.get(1).isTurn = false;
                        clients.get(0).isTurn = true;
                    }

                }


            }
            //Read input from the client
            //DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
            //If we decide to hit
            //if(dataInputStream.readUTF().equals("1"))
            //{
                //We want to send a random score 1-14
                //rand = new Random();
              //  temp = rand.nextInt(14);

            //}


           //DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            //dataOutputStream.writeUTF(Integer.toString(temp));
            //dataOutputStream.flush();


              // server.close();
        }
         catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }

    }


}


public static void main(String [] args)
{
    int port = 9999;
    try
    {
        Thread t = new Server(port);
        t.start();
    }catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You have some `while(true)` statements.

Comment: In the server you should implement a loop listeneing for connections, and then spawn a thread to handle that connection.
Search the web for `EchoServer` for some hints